# Identify D3.js Graph

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, data-visualization, arc-diagram

What is this graph called that was generated by [D3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/stack.html)?

[image]

Is there a name for it?

I failed to describe it when looking for keywords in the documentation and spent quite a bit of time scouring the web.

Once identifying it, what is one example in the D3 documentation that includes a graph similar to this? I can't appear to find any that would resemble this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is most likely built via the [bundle layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Bundle-Layout).

Answer (score 2):

This diagram is called *arc diagram*.

---

An interesting background on arc diagrams can be found at [this Manuel Lima's blog post](http://www.visualcomplexity.com/vc/blog/?p=1159). It includes some historical facts and these intriguing illustrations:

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

There are several examples of arc diagrams made with D3:

### Example 1

[Characters from "Les Miserables"](http://bl.ocks.org/sjengle/5431779), by Sophie Engle.

[image]

### Example 2

[Chapters of "The DaVinci Code"](http://www.ghostweather.com/essays/talks/openvisconf/topic_arc_diagram/TopicArc.html), by Lynn Cherny.

[image]

### Example 3

[Result of Stanford natural language parser applied to a sentence](http://bl.ocks.org/goodmami/fd03b250588e1e1143bd), by Michael Wayne Goodman.

[image]

### Example 4

[Arc diagrams of RNA secondary structures](http://www.e-rna.org/r-chie/) by Daniel Lai, Jeff R. Proctor, Jing Yun A. Zhu, and Irmtraud M. Meyer.

[image]